# Not able to see archive page of custom posts

Tags: custom-post-type-archives

I am using Wordpress 5.4. I created a CPT using the code below:

```
$args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => 'Some description',
    'public'        => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
    'has_archive'   => true,
  );
register_post_type( 'article', $args );
```

`has_archive` was set to true and my understanding is that now when I goto `/articles` I am supposed to see all posts of type `article`. But that is not the case. When I goto `/articles` I see my normal posts. I do not have any `article-archive.php` on my system and understand that is not necessary. I do have a `./wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/archive.php` and I am using a child theme of `twnetynineteen` on my site.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**:

1. I have tried `/article` and it does not fix the problem.
2. I have tried resaving permalinks (Settings->Permalinks) and it does not fix the problem.
3. The code above is located in a plugin.
4. I **can** see my article if I goto `/?article=test-article` where `test-article` is slug of my article.
5. I am using `nginx` with [this](https://gist.github.com/md5/d9206eacb5a0ff5d6be0#file-wordpress-fpm-conf) configuration.

Comment: technically the archive slug should be `/article/` not `/articles/`. The default `archive.php` file should be able to display your articles.

Comment: `/article` also does not work

Comment: Where is the code in your question located? Do permalinks work for other post types and pages? What are your permalinks set to?

Comment: Permalinks are set to `/?p=123` in `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to use **Post name** in `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> has_archive was set to true and my understanding is that now when I goto /articles I am supposed to see all posts of type article.

Nowhere in your code is article*S* mentioned, the slug of the post type is `article`, so the URL of its archive should be `/article/`. If you want it to be `articles` you have to say so.

In this case, it's the classic mistake of registering a post type or taxonomy, but not flushing permalinks to add their rules. Go to the permalinks setting page, and resave.

As for the template `archive.php`, this is irrelevant to wether the page loads or not. The template hierarchy will fallback to `index.php` which is required for a theme if no other templats are found. Additionally, `archive.php` doesn't make the URL an archive. The URL makes it an archive, and the fact it's an archive makes WP load that template. WP has already figured out what posts to fetch before the template is chosen.

Comment: I have tried both those things as well. using `/article` and resaving permalinks. I also tried looking at the WP error log `wp-content/debug.log` and there is nothing in it. I can access my article if I goto `/?article=test-article`

Comment: So no permalinks work for your article post type at all? That's new and very important information you did not share.